# Excel: Find if value exist and return value in new column

Tags: excel

I have tried all week to find a solution to this. I have tried over 25 formulas but I cannot find one that does what I need it to do and I do not have a lot of experience with formulas in Excel.

Here is what I need to do:

I have a column with some abbreviated states (column "F") and I need to be able to find a particular state and have it return the value in column "G" if it matches.

Column F:

```
TX
FL, TN
MA, MI, NY, OH, VA
TN, MI, VA
```

If "TN" is in column F, then post "TN" in column G, on the same row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values are in Col F starting from row 1, type this formula in G1 and copy it down.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("TN",F1,1)),"","TN")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=IFERROR(MID(F1,FIND("TN",F1),2),"")
```

in cell G1. Copy-and-paste down.